# my selected option in the dropdown select menu does not update immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My issue is that when I select an option from the menu it does not update it's value (it doesn't even show the selected option). I have to click on it again or click on another option for it to select the previous one.

I have tried using a useEffect to update the value which partially worked. Now when I console log it shows the updated value but the option that is visible is still not in sync.

This is the part of the code that has the issue. (x is an array filled from a firestore database)

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'


const Home = () => {
  const [entree, setEntree] = useState();
const entryRows = [];



for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  entryRows.push(
   <option value={i} key={Math.random()}>
   {i}
   </option>
  );}

useEffect(() => {
console.log(entree);
}, [entree]);


return (
  <div className='container'>
<div className="row">
    <select
          className="form-select mb-3 col ps-0 me-3 py-3"
          aria-label="Default select example"
          onChange={(e) =>{
            setEntree(e.target.value)
          }}>
     <option value="" defaultValue>Select an entry</option>
    {entryRows}
   </select>
</div>
</div>
)
}

export default Home;
```

As you see in the code I have used useEffect which was said to be the solution in other similar questions to try to get the correct value from "entree", and it does give the correct value but the selected option will be the previously selected one.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  The code shown has a syntax error, `x` is never defined, etc.

Comment: @David I just updated it. Sorry for that I am still a beginner when it comes to both react and using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply aren't setting the *value* for the `<select>`:

```
<select
  className="form-select mb-3 col ps-0 me-3 py-3"
  aria-label="Default select example"
  value={entree}
  onChange={(e) =>{
    setEntree(e.target.value)
  }}>
  <option value="" defaultValue>Select an entry</option>
  {entryRows}
</select>
```

Basically you're using a custom `onChange` to update state, and in doing so you would also need to use state to drive the current value of the element.